# Is it possible to integrate JPBM 6 with jboss 4.3?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I am working on a POC where we will be evaluating jbpm 6, we have few applications which are deployed on jboss 4.3. Is it possible to integrate these two ?

Comment: Please proceed with latest version

Comment: you can create separate project for all jBPM flows, deploy that on later version of Jboss and access from applications deployed on 4.3.